# Global Search is able to find the records while advanced search is returning zero records- Is this Salesforce Bug

Tags: apex, search, global-search, advanced

I have looking for account using account number field which is unique in each account. Global Search is able to find the record while advance search is saying no record. Is this salesforce bug or any thing I can make user find records when they use Advanced search.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the 'advanced search' ? any screenshots you can share?

Comment: Thanks glls for quick reply. I just attached the picture of advanced search. Just to let  you know Advanced search feature only come on your screen when chatter is disabled for that profile.